# Try to continue after certain time at failed boot

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, usb

I have an old computer that I didn't really use much so I decided to dig it out and try booting it from a Linux Mint USB flash drive, unfortunately I didn't have a keyboard for it.

I couldn't use mine since mine is plugged into the back of my current computer and I dont want to have to crawl over/under my desk to unplug it so then plug it into the computer.

So I thought I would do it only once, I would plug it in, go into linux, set up the wifi for the computer and other stuff, enable onscreen keyboard for when I don't have the one for my main computer, then set up the boot order to try booting from the USB first because whenever I tried booting with the USB just plugged in, it would say it couldn't find the hard-drive, so I figured I would change the boot order to try to find the USB instead of the hard drive, now it still says the message but it says to press F1 to try again, whenever I do that it then boots to the USB, but that still means whenever I boot I have to have a keyboard in.

I think it's because it isn't recognizing the USB fast enough and when I retry it is ready to boot from. So what I want to do is somehow add a timer that will automatically continue with F1 after 5-10 seconds or so.

**EDIT**

i found out why, inside my system setup, though i had disabled attempting to boot from other drives, i still had drives that it would try to boot from enabled under "Drives-DRIVES", i unselected them all and now i boot up perfectly normal without having to press any keys, i found the answer here: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/t/19406582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out why(This is the author of this questions BTW), inside my system setup, though i had disabled attempting to boot from other drives, i still had drives that it would try to boot from enabled under "Drives-DRIVES", i unselected them all and now i boot up perfectly normal without having to press any keys, i found the answer here: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/t/19406582